# Why does margin on H1 not space between parent div?

Tags: css

I am making a basic header for a site and the margin of the `H1` element is moving my heading section down.

I can set the margin to `0` on `H1` but I'd rather understand why the margin of `H1` isn't creating space with my `top-nav` `div`

```css
html, body, .home {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

h1{
  font-size: 72px;
  /* margin: 0;*/
}

.main-title{
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  color: #b5b8c2;
}

.top-nav{
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #111a21;
}
```

```html
<header class="home">
        <div class="top-nav">
          <h1><span class="main-title">My Title</span></h1>
        </div>
</header>
```

Why doesnt the `H1` margin align to the `top-nav` `div`?

Comment: We need to explain it to him not show him not close at first second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The margin of your h1 is outside its parent. You can force the parent to wrap the margin like this:

```
.top-nav {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `display: block` will push the parent in margin.
To fix this add `display: inline-block` or `display: table;` to the h1.

```
h1 {
 display: table;
}
```

Or you can remove the `margin` and add `padding` instead.